# Confusion with Pytest optimization to speed up testing

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django

This is not going to be a coding specific question, I honestly just have been attempting to speed up testing for my project the last week or so using `pytest`, `pytest-xdist` and `pytest-django` and I feel like I am running into a wall with optimization now.

I have 3047 tests spanning my project. I am fully aware that database access inside of pytest slows down testing times, but I honestly feel like most of them require DB access as it is a database-driven system, but running my CI, my tests are taking about 12-14 minutes to complete. It's not that bad, but I used to have a full test-to-deploy time right around 10 minutes and I guess since I just added quite a few new tests to cover everything a bit more in depth, the time has increased to about 15 minutes. Again, not bad, I just want to improve it.

I run my tests from my root directory via `pytest -n auto`

Is there anything I can do to speed up my tests that I may be overlooking? I realize that is a somewhat challenging question to answer without seeing my individual tests, but I'm asking more in concept because most of my tests look similar (give or take some fixtures) to this:

```
def test_cannot_login_staff_with_over_5_errors(self, client, slug, admin):
    url = reverse('login', args=[slug])
    admin.has_two_factor_authentication = False
    # store human readable portions of the user so we can log them in
    admin.set_password('password')
    admin.save()

    data = {
        'username': admin.username,
        'password': 'password-Not',
    }

    for i in range(0,6):    # will try 4 times
        response = client.post(url, data)
        # will redirect on successful login
        if i < 4:   # on the 5th it does redirect
            print(i)
            assert response.status_code == 200
        else:
            assert response.status_code == 302
```

I have tried collecting files more quickly (although this actually doesn't speed things up much) with this:

`{ find -name 'test*.py'; } | xargs pytest`

I have removed all logic, other that the required `client` object from my tests, so 'setup' objects are being configured only when needed (in my attempt to limit as much db access as possible). For example here is 1 fixture that is required in nearly every test:

```
@pytest.fixture
def slug(db):
    #     with connections.cursor() as cursor:
    #         cursor.execute(
    #             """
    #             INSERT INTO client_info(
    #               name, price_per_unit, price_per_website, url_base, date_entered, last_update, uuid, is_active, deleted_by_cascade)
    #               VALUES('test', 1.99, 148.99, 'test', NOW(), NOW(), 'f15cf30a-3d69-44db-ab2c-58c6608717ad', True, False)
    #             """
    #         )

    client = mommy.make('client.ClientInformation', url='test', name='test')

    return client.url
```

I then started thinking that if it were possible to not call the `slug` fixture in almost every test, perhaps that would speed things up a bit so I went to sessionstart and attempted to add db access to do this, but any possible way I try to allow db access fails with `RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.`, for example:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    from django.test import TestCase
    TestCase.multi_db = True
    TestCase.databases = '__all__'
    client = mommy.make('client.ClientInformation', url_base='test', name='test', price_per_unit=1.99)


# or....
# Argument(s) {'db'} are declared in the hookimpl but can not be found in the hookspec
def pytest_sessionstart(session, db):
    from django.test import TestCase
    TestCase.multi_db = True
    TestCase.databases = '__all__'
    client = mommy.make('client.ClientInformation', url_base='test', name='test', price_per_unit=1.99)
```

Comment: as a general comment, if you are seeing performance problems you need to understand what parts of the code are slow - that means timing the execution of the code in such a way that you can know how much time is spent in which parts of the code. Otherwise you will start optimizing things that do not contribute to the total time significantly,

Comment: I agree with the above comment. You can view the "slowest" tests by utilizing the `durations` arg as referenced here -- https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/example/simple.html#profiling-test-duration